# Spring data mongoDB lazy configuration of database connection

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, multi-tenant, spring-data-mongodb

I have a multi-tenant mongoDB application and let's assume that 
right connection to right database is chosen from tenant name from HTTP request header(i usage earlier prepared properties file with tenant name). 
When application is started mongoDB is configuring and i don't have information about tenant, because none request to application hasn't been sent, so i don't know to which database i should be connect. Is a possibility that mongoDB connection to database would be configured dynamicly, when I try to get some data from mongo repository(then I have tenant name from HTTP request)?

MongoDbConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class MongoDbConfiguration {

    private final MongoConnector mongoConnector;

    @Autowired
    public MongoDbConfiguration(MongoConnector mongoConnector) {
        this.mongoConnector = mongoConnector;
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory() {
        return new MultiTenantSingleMongoDbFactory(mongoConnector, new MongoExceptionTranslator());
    }

    @Bean
    public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate() {
        return new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Component
@Slf4j
public class MultiTenantMongoDbFactory extends SimpleMongoDbFactory {

  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MultiTenantMongoDbFactory.class);

  private Map<String, DbConfig> tenantToDbConfig;

  private Map<String, MongoDatabase> tenantToMongoDatabase;

  @Autowired
  public MultiTenantMongoDbFactory(
      final @Qualifier("sibTenantContexts") Map<String, DbConfig> dbConfigs,
      final SibEnvironment env) {

    super(new MongoClientURI(env.getDefaultDatabase()));
    this.tenantToDbConfig = dbConfigs;
    // Initialize tenantToMongoDatabase map.
    buildTenantDbs();
  }

  @Override
  public MongoDatabase getDb() {

    String tenantId = (!StringUtils.isEmpty(TenantContext.getId()) ? TenantContext.getId()
        : SibConstant.DEFAULT_TENANT);
    return this.tenantToMongoDatabase.get(tenantId);
  }

  /**
   * Create tenantToMongoDatabase map.
   */
  @SuppressWarnings("resource")
  private void buildTenantDbs() {

    log.debug("Building tenantDB configuration.");
    this.tenantToMongoDatabase = new HashMap<>();
    /*
     * for each tenant fetch dbConfig and intitialize MongoClient and set it to
     * tenantToMongoDatabase
     */
    for (Entry<String, DbConfig> idToDbconfig : this.tenantToDbConfig.entrySet()) {
      try {
        this.tenantToMongoDatabase.put(idToDbconfig.getKey(),
            new MongoClient(new MongoClientURI(idToDbconfig.getValue()
                .getUri())).getDatabase(idToDbconfig.getValue()
                    .getDatabase()));
      } catch (MongoException e) {
        log.error(e.getMessage(), e.getCause());
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In this, `tenantToDbConfig` is a bean which I have created at the time of application boot where I store DBConfiguration like (Url/database name) against every tenant. There is one default database which is required at boot time and for every request, I am expecting tenantId in request Header.